# Illegal Instruction (core dumped) when starting eager execution

Tags: python, tensorflow

On a fresh instance of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I've installed tensor flow (version 1.8.0) with

```
pip install tensorflow
sudo apt install python-tk
pip install matplotlib
```

My main.py file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

tf.enable_eager_execution()

print("TensorFlow version: {}".format(tf.VERSION))
print("Eager execution: {}".format(tf.executing_eagerly()))
```

However, when running "python main.py" I get

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Any tips on what I might have done wrong, or what I can try to fix this? I've already tried downgrading to 1.7.0 (and 1.5.0, but that didn't have eager execution).

Source:
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/eager

Edit: Moved pip/install commands to code block for clarity

Comment: Do you get the same error even without enabling eager execution, but instead doing something like `sess = tf.Session()`? I wonder if your CPU doesn't support AVX instructions. [Since TensorFlow 1.6](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.6.0), the binary releases require such instructions which may break on older CPUs.

Comment: @ash - Yes that's right - it's independent of eager execution. Same error with `sess = tf.Session()`. I probably have too old of a CPU, I wonder if there's a way to identify that upon installation, or during initialization? Instead of core-dumping